# Proving that every chain in a Dedekind-finite poset has an upper bound

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

I'd like to be able to prove the statement in the title's subordinate clause: if $P$ is a Dedekind-finite partially ordered set and $T \subset P$ is totally ordered, then $T$ has an upper bound in $P$. Here's what I've tried, essentially building up the natural numbers inside $T$ using AC using an approach based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2864310/425582), but I'd like to know 1) how to finish up this proof if it can be made to work, 2) if there is a proof that uses a weaker choice axiom, or none at all, and 3) if there is a proof that avoids the natural numbers.

Let $(P, \leq)$ be a partially ordered set and $T \subset P$ a nonempty, totally ordered subset with no upper bound in $P$. Use AC to define $\sigma: T \to T$ by choosing some $\sigma(t) > t$ for each $t \in T$. Choose some $z \in T$ and consider the collection of all subsets $S \subset T$ satisfying $z \in S$, $z \leq s$ for all $s \in S$, and $\sigma(S) \subset S$; this collection is nonempty since it contains the set $\{ s \in T: z \leq s \}$. Let $N$ be the intersection of all such subsets $S$. Clearly $N$ is nonempty since it contains $z$, and also $\sigma(N) \subset N$.

At this point, I'd like to be able to show that $N$ is well-ordered by $\leq$ and that $\sigma$ acts on $N$ as the successor function, i.e. $\sigma(n) = \min\{m \in N: m > n \}$. This would imply that $\sigma$ is an injection, proving that $P$ contains a Dedekind-infinite set and is therefore Dedekind-infinite, proving the desired statement by contrapositive.

However, I have no clue how to show that $N$ is well-ordered by $\leq$, if in fact it is, and I'd be interested in seeing a proof that doesn't build up this much machinery. It feels there's probably a simple argument I'm not seeing.

Comment: Isn't "every chain in a nonempty Dedekind-finite poset has an upper bound" equivalent to "every nonempty Dedekind-finite totally ordered set has a greatest element"? Is there some advantage to stating it in the more general form?

Comment: @bof Yes, you're quite right! I didn't realize that while I was typing it. I've actually found a solution, which is a little less heavy-handed than "take the intersection of everything in the room and hope for the best", but I'm not sure about the etiquette of answering one's own question.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly fine.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4680/is-answering-own-question-okay

Comment: Even many quite weak forms of Choice imply that Dedekind-finite = finite, so is there any point in attempting a proof that uses AC?

Comment: @DavidHartley There's definitely no point if one's concern is to keep the choice assumptions to a minimum. My own interest is in how much one is forced to refer more or less explicitly to the natural numbers in order to prove things about Dedekind-finite sets. This is just a weird rabbit hole I'm going down because I get a kick out of the definition of Dedekind-finiteness and want to see what you can do with it if you allow yourself to use AC with reckless abandon, so I guess the point is my own amusement.

Answer (score 1):

As bof observed, your claim is equivalent to, every non-empty totally-ordered Dedekind-finite set has a maximum. But that implies every non-empty subset of such a set also has a maximum and, by reversing the order, a minimum. I.e. every such set is well-ordered and so finite. There are apparently models of ZF with infinite, Dedekind-finite sets of reals and so your claim cannot be proved without some extra assumption.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out -- I've got a proof that uses Zorn quite liberally, and will post it for completeness, but it's good to know that something more than ZF really is necessary.